# How do I check diagonal win in TIC Tac Toe?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a Tic Tac Toe game in JavaScript and HTML. In the game the user can choose on how many columes and rows he wants to play. I was abble to check win in a row and a colum but I don't have any idea for a diagonal.
Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var rows;
var cols;
var Array;
var tor = 0;
function XO() {
    rows = +prompt("Enter rows : ");
    cols = +prompt("Enter cols : ");

    intBoard = new Array(rows);
    var r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < intBoard.length; r++) {
        intBoard[r] = new Array(cols);
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            intBoard[r][c] = 0;
        }
    }

    var idNum = 0;
    var strToShow = "<table border='1'>";
    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        strToShow = strToShow + "<tr>";
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            strToShow = strToShow + "<td id='" + idNum.toString() +
                " ' onclick='TdClicked(this)' width='80px' height='80px' >";
            //strToShow = strToShow + idNum.toString();
            strToShow = strToShow + "<img src='background.jpg' width='80px' height='80px' />";
            strToShow = strToShow + "</td>";
            idNum++;
        }
        strToShow = strToShow + "</tr>";
    }
    strToShow = strToShow + "</table>";
    document.write(strToShow);
}


var showfirst = 0;
function TdClicked(tdClickedThis) {
    var idClicked = tdClickedThis.id;
    var rowClicked = Math.floor(idClicked / cols);
    var colClicked = idClicked % cols;

    if (showfirst == 0) {
        document.getElementById(idClicked).innerHTML = "<img width='80px' height='80px' src='wolf.jpg'/>";
        showfirst++;
        intBoard[rowClicked][colClicked] = 1;

        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {           // check win in column
            if (intBoard[rowClicked][c] != 1)
                c = cols + 111;   //break;
        }
        if (c == cols)
            alert("PLAYER X WIN!!")


        for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {           // check win in row
            if (intBoard[r][colClicked] != 1)
                r = rows + 111;   //break;
        }
        if (r == rows)
            alert("PLAYER X WIN!!")


        
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById(idClicked).innerHTML = "<img width='80px' height='80px' src='fox.png'/>";
        showfirst--;
        intBoard[rowClicked][colClicked] = 2;

        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {            //check win in column
            if (intBoard[rowClicked][c] != 2)
                c = cols + 111;   //break;
        }
        if (c == cols)
            alert("PLAYER O WIN!!")


        for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {            // check win in row
            if (intBoard[r][colClicked] != 2)
                r = rows + 111;   //break;
        }
        if (r == rows)
            alert("PLAYER O WIN!!")

    }
}
```

Comment: For a field of 5 cols and 4 rows, a three field `\` diagonal will start anywhere inside col 0 to col 5-3 = 2, and row 0 or row 4-3 = 1. So you need to iterate over the top 2 rows and 3 leftmost columns then go down and over from that field each time, counting matches. Three nested for loops basically. Then the same for `/` diagonals, this time from the right edge.

Comment: Note that I'd use a one-dimensional array for this, which makes looking for three in a row much easier.